# Rookie Python-questions, array indexing issue

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array indexing issue.

There is a 2d array dataSet

(800, 600, value in depth) # image width, image height, and gray scale.

I want to transfer to 3D array(X,Y,Depth)

```
# pre-define
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
# from txt to array 
file = ('..location\data.TXT')

# 2D data in value
data2D = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t')

# 1D data in array
data1D = data2D.flatten()

# convert to 3d array[X,Y,depth]
w = data2D.shape[0]
h = data2D.shape[1]
try:
    for y in range (0,h):
        for x in range (0,w):
            idx = y * w + x
            xyz = np.array([y,x,new[idx]])
except:
    pass
```

```
result:
    run okay!
    wrong result.
```

Here is my question:
I know its a bug and simple issue.
I found no clue online when learning Python(Do Have some experience with C/C++ and MATLAB) 
How can I make this right? new to Python, also some hint or suggestion!
Many Thanks! :)

## Updated

- fixed with indentation

## My Goal

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6d4l.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84E70.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of errors, you are missing a `]` on `xyz[y, x, new[idx]] = new[idx]`. Put that back in and it should fix one error.

Also in python if you want to use `try`, you need to have an except clause. If you don't want it, you can just have an empty `pass` statement in there.

```
# pre-define
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# from txt to array
file = ('..location\data.TXT')

# 2D data in value
data2D = np.loadtxt(file, delimiter='\t')

# 1D data in array
data1D = digits.flatten()

# width / height
w = data2D.shape[0]
h = data2D.shape[1]

# try to convert to 3d array[X,Y,depth]
try:
    for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            idx = y * w + x
            xyz[y, x, new[idx]] = new[idx]
except:
    pass
```

Comment: It surprise me what a quick answer. thank you so much!

Comment: @DC.Hacker If the answer solves your issue, please consider marking the question as resolved by checking the tick next to the answer. :)

Comment: Still have some issue about it, updated

Comment: Your indentation is still off. Please indent the lines after `try:`. That error is not there in the code that I have posted. Please use the exact code when trying it out.

Comment: done with the indentation

Comment: If you have issues with the result, that's a completely different issue. You shouldn't try to resolve that along with other type of errors like indentation. And that would also need a lot more details like what exactly result were you expecting, what did you get, and what your attempt was to solve it. You also need to make sure that the code is reproducible by someone trying to run it. In your current code, `digits` is not defined. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidelines for asking a question.

Comment: I see that you have included your expected result etc I still maintain that this needs to be opened as a new issue. Otherwise, you are asking for too much in a single question. Each question needs to have a single focused solution as explained in the guidelines. You cannot expect people who are volunteering to help you to spend their time fixing each issue that you come across sequentially.

Comment: I see! Thanks again for your advice, Ananda! :)

Comment: I'll do more effort on it

Answer (score 0):

`np.expand_dims()` Search about this"

You can use `np.reshape()`

Comment: ok I'll try it!

Comment: Also in python indentation is important. Try to fix in your code where you write ``try / except``

Comment: got it i figure it out